# Angular 2 jest input delegate test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5, angular2-directives, jestjs

I have a problem with the unit-testing delegate component, which should block special keys and allow the input of data matching the regular expression.

The directive component code is:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[w2NumberLimit]',
})
export class NumberLimitDirective {
  @Input() public integerLimit: number = 10;
  @Input() public fractionalLimit: number = 0;
  @Input() public decimalMark: string = ',';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) public onKeyPress(event) {
     const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
     const regexp = RegExp(this.setRegexp(), 'g');

     if (next && !String(next).match(regexp)) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
  }

private setRegexp() {
    let regexp: string = '^[0-9]';

    // set integer part limit
    regexp = regexp + ((this.integerLimit) ? `{0,${this.integerLimit}}` : '*');

    // set fractionalLimit
    regexp = regexp + ((this.fractionalLimit > 0) ? `(\\${this.decimalMark}[0-9]{0,${this.fractionalLimit}})?` : '');

    return regexp + '$';
  }
}
```

Unit test code:

```
describe('Directive: NumberLimitDirective', () => {
  let component: TestNumberLimitComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestNumberLimitComponent>;
  let inputAutoFocusEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NumberLimitDirective, TestNumberLimitComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestNumberLimitComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputAutoFocusEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();
  });

  function sendInput(inputElement: any, text: number | string) {
    const value = inputElement.nativeElement.value;
    inputElement.nativeElement.value = value.concat(text);
    const event = new Event('input');
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
  }

  function sendKeyDown(inputElement: any, event: any) {
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
  }

  function testInput(inputElement: any, text: number | string) {
    const oneKeyDown = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {key: `${text}`});
    sendKeyDown(inputElement, oneKeyDown);
    if (!oneKeyDown.defaultPrevented) {
      sendInput(inputElement, text);
    }
  }

  test('Check valid input for default input.', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const testLocator = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#default'));
    expect(testLocator).not.toBe(null);
    await testInput(testLocator, 1);
    await testInput(testLocator, ',');
    await testInput(testLocator, 0);
    jest.runAllTicks();
    expect(testLocator.nativeElement.value).toBe('01');
  });
});
```

Test component code:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <input id="default" w2NumberLimit [value]="test" [(ngModel)]="test" #input="ngModel">
    </div>`
})
export class TestNumberLimitComponent {
  public test = 0;
}
```

By default this component should ignore "," and "0". So output value should be "01", but preventDefault field of event doesn't change its value to "true".

In the same time this directive works with input directly when i use it in my application. With same input it blocks last "," and "0" inputs.

Comment: I guess there is an issue with awaiting non-promise-returning functions.
It seems like you want to wait for `testInput` using `await`, but you do not return a promise from `testIntput`, is this correct?
You should also not mix Promises (`await`) with Angular means of async tests (`detectChanges`, `fakeAsync`, ...)

Comment: I will check this.  Thanks for the tip!